# Can address be loaded in a cache but not in the main memory?

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, paging, cpu-cache, page-fault

Can memory address be loaded in a cache but not in the main memory? In other words, if cache wants to write data into the main memory, can that generate page fault in x86-64 with Linux?

Answer (score 3):

No, cache is transparent (and [in x86-64 caches by physical address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092541/which-cache-mapping-technique-is-used-in-intel-core-i7-processor)).  Only load or store instructions (and code-fetch) can page fault, and that happens synchronously (on the offending instruction), not some random time later.

Of course, actual commit to L1d cache is delayed ([by the store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram)) until after retirement from the out-of-order execution back-end.  But checking for faults is done in the load/store execution unit (which for stores, writes data and address into the store buffer for it to definitely happen and become visible some time later.)

Comment: Technically, a memory access could complete before the page was returned to memory (or paged-out memory) or allocated/zeroed (for new memory). The Mill's backless memory does this for unallocated pages (reads provide a zero cache block, writes write into cache (which is virtually addressed). This is "easy" for zero copy-on-write pages, for swapped pages interleaving as the swapped data becomes available would be more complex (but still doable). Even with a physically tagged cache, one could use "shadow pages" to for tagging.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Interesting, I'll have to read up on that sometime.  One could also mention x86's "cache as ram" / "no fill" mode, but that doesn't apply to the "normal program running" use-case, while The Mill does speed up normal programs with that trick.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: unrelated, you probably already saw this recent cpu-architecture question, but if not, I'd be interested in your feedback on my guesswork in [How do weak ISAs resolve WAW memory hazards using the store buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66224125).  (This comment will self-destruct).