# How do weak ISAs resolve WAW memory hazards using the store buffer?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Modern CPUs use a store buffer to delay commit into cache until retirement, also avoiding WAR and WAW *memory* hazards. I'm wondering how weak ISAs resolve WAW hazards using the store buffer, which is otherwise not a FIFO, allowing StoreStore reordering? Do they insert an implicit barrier?

More specifically, if two stores to the same memory address retire in-order on a weak ISA, e.g. ARM/POWER, they could theoretically commit to cache *out-of-order*, since the store buffer is not FIFO, thus breaking the WAW dependency.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_disambiguation#Avoiding_WAR_and_WAW_dependencies):

> ...the store instructions, including the memory address and store data, are buffered in a store queue until they reach the retirement point. When a store retires, it then writes its value to the memory system. This avoids the WAR and WAW dependence problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My guess; I'm not familiar with the details of any real-world designs

Even if the store buffer is a full scheduler that can "grab" any graduated store for commit to L1d, **I'd assume it would use an oldest-ready first order.**  (Like an instruction / uop scheduler aka RS Reservation Station.)

"Ready" would mean the cache line is exclusively owned (Modified or Exclusive state). Every graduated store itself is implicitly ready to commit because by  definition the associated store instruction has retired.

In-order retirement means that stores become eligible for commit in program-order, so you can't have an older store that's temporarily hidden from the oldest-ready-first scheduling.
**Together, those things would ensure that for any given byte, stores overlapping it are in program order** and thus maintain consistency of global-visibility order and final value for any given group of bytes within a cache line.

A memory barrier might work by fencing off the store buffer like a divider on a grocery-store checkout conveyor belt, preventing grabbing of stores past it while committing ones to the same place in the same line.

We do know real-world weakly-ordered store buffers like [PowerPC RS64-III (in-order exec) and Alpha 21264 (OoO exec)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225485/224132) do merging to help them create whole 4-byte or 8-byte aligned commits to L1d, e.g. out of multiple byte stores.  That's also fine, assuming your merge algorithm respects order for any given byte e.g. by putting the data from a younger store into an older SB entry or vice versa and marking the other entry as "already committed".  Obviously this must respect store barriers.

I think this is all fine even with unaligned stores, although preserving atomicity guarantees for unaligned stores could be tricky with merging.  (Intel P6-family and later does provide atomicity guarantees for unaligned cached stores that don't cross a cache-line boundary, but we don't think Intel does merging in the store buffer proper; maybe just some stuff with LFBs for cache-miss back-to-back stores to the same line.)

It's likely that real hardware might not be a full scheduler that can merge any 2 SB entries, e.g. maybe only over limited range to reduce the amount of different addresses (and sizes) to compare at once.  Also, you'd probably still only free up SB entries in program order, so it can basically be a circular buffer (unlike the RS).  Alloc in program order, and having the order be tracked by the layout of the SB itself, makes it much cheaper for memory barriers to work, and to track where the youngest "graduated" store is.

### Disclaimer: IDK if this is exactly how real HW works

---

Possible corner case: unaligned 4-byte store to `[cache_line+63]` (split across a CL boundary) and then to `[cache_line+60]` (fully contained in the lower cache line).  If the older store-buffer entry can't commit right away because we don't yet own the *next* cache line, but we do own `cache_line`, we still can't let the younger store to `cache_line+60` commit first, if we're depending on that not happening to avoid WAW hazards.

So you'd probably want a line-split SB entry to be able to commit the data to one line but not the other, allowing oldest-ready-first to happen for each location separately, not tying together order across 2 cache lines.

---

Related: I wrote [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) explaining what a store buffer is.  I tried to avoid mistakes like Wikipedia makes ("*when* a store retires, it writes its value to the memory system":  In fact retirement just makes it eligible to commit; such stores are called "graduated" stores.)

Comment: Very interesting points! It all sounds truly convincing to me :) 
"_So you'd probably want a line-split SB entry to be able to commit the data to one line but not the other_" talk about corner cases...

Comment: Cache-line splits are not all that rare on x86.  (But it has a strongly-ordered memory model).  We *think* a single store always takes 1 SB entry (except for something like `fstp tword [mem]` 10-byte store which is actually multiple separate store-data uops, presumably 8-byte and 2-byte), because there's be no good way to allocate another SB entry when we finally execute a store and discover that it's a cache-line split. [Are two store buffer entries needed for split line/page stores on recent Intel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61180829)

Comment: RISCs that allow unaligned stores efficiently (without a special instruction) may use a very different strategy, IDK.  (Hmm, this may have something to do with why `movups` 16-byte load/store was always multiple uops on older x86 CPUs, to always have an extra SB entry allocated in case of need.  Especially with K10 having single uop movups loads, but multi-uop movups stores.  Even Core 2 and K8 have single-uop 8-byte stores which can be split, but maybe it's a matter of how much spare space there is in an SB entry to track separate commit to diff. lines, or to hold more data.)

Comment: A cache-line split store, followed by a partially overlapping store (that doesn't straddle a cache boundary). I guess there is real code out there that might end up doing that :0

Comment: @DanielNitzan: oh right, somewhat more rare, but I'd expect that to happen regularly in [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240).  Or other code that stores more than it needs to take advantage of the store-buffer + cache's ability to absorb such writes, like a 4->3 packing function that ends up with 15 bytes it wants to store but actually stores 16, and advances a pointer by the much. Or glibc memcpy that handles e.g. 4..7 byte copies with 2 overlapping 4-byte loads and corresponding stores, same for other load/store sizes.