# How is coherence implemented in multi-level caches?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, micro-architecture, mesi

I have understood how the cache coherence FSM works for single private L1 cache and a common LLC/memory. But couldn't find good resources where they discuss about cache coherence when there are 2 private caches - L1  and L2 and a common memory. I don't understand where the interconnection  network is placed in the whole model, what does L1 caches snoop and their FSM.

Comment: Usually modern designs use directory-based coherency so you don't have a common snoopable bus as a bottleneck for all cores' traffic to LLC.  Semi-related: [Which cache mapping technique is used in intel core i7 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092541) mentions how Intel uses inclusive L3 tags as the directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache coherency(MESI protocol) between different levels of cache namely L1, L2 and L3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731349/cache-coherencymesi-protocol-between-different-levels-of-cache-namely-l1-l2-a)