# CPU Cache Behaviour when Data Changes

Tags: c, caching, cpu, cpu-cache

I was just wondering about how data changes affect the CPU cache.

Let's say I have the following C code:

```
int main() {
  int arr[16] = ...

  for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   arr[i] += arr[i];
  }
}
```

How many times does the CPU have to reload the numbers in cache because of the memory writes in each of the loops?

Comment: The performance of a block of code as it relates to a cache depends on many factors, but **cache locality** is probably the most important.

Comment: Reloading a recent store should hit in cache with a simple access pattern like this (not also accessing other memory in between that might be a multiple of 4k away, or whatever could alias).  Or store-to-load forward from the store buffer if it hasn't even committed to L1d cache yet.  In any real-world CPU with a cache, it would normally be big enough to cache 16 `int`s, so you'd expect the 2nd loop to get all L1d cache hits when it runs right after the first loop primed the cache.  I wouldn't expect any L1d misses except maybe in the stores to the stack from the `= ...`.

Comment: you need to read about TLB and TLB hit and miss

Answer (score 4):

The exact answer depends on the machine-specific details of the cache configuration. The only way to know for sure in general is to measure using the hardware counters and a tool like [PAPI](https://icl.utk.edu/papi/).

However in general, writes from a core will update a copy in the L1 cache, so that a subsequent read of the same address later will return the updated copy from cache without a miss (assuming the cache line hasn't been evicted in the interval).

For the code you show (1-d array with 16 4-byte elements), you're only dealing with 64 bytes which is 1 cache line on most modern processors (or 2 depending on alignment), so it's very likely to be loaded into L1 cache at the start when you initialize the elements, and operate in-cache for both loops (assuming there are no other conflicting accesses from other threads).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. One quick question: is there a chance that each time the values of the array are modified the loaded cache line is actually being invalidated? That would require a memory load at each iteration instead of just one in total.

Comment: @scasci: No, unless you used x86 `_mm_stream_si32` stores (`movnti`, cache-bypassing: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movnti).  Compilers of course won't do that on their own because it would be a performance disaster.  A cache that does write-invalidate would be a terrible design, nobody does that.  Some CPUs have had write-*through*, updating the data in cache while also passing it through to the next outer level of cache. (In x86, as recent as AMD Bulldozer-family, although that was widely considered a poor design.)

Comment: See also [Which cache mapping technique is used in intel core i7 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092541)

Comment: @PeterCordes With **really stupid** compiler autoparallelization distributing the work to different cores/caches at word granularity, write invalidate would effectively be used. Perhaps a compiler for the old (cacheless) Tera might do something like that?